# Are ehcache putAll Operations Thread Safe and Atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, ehcache

The documentation says that ehcache is thread safe. So as far as I understand if `thread A` updates a cache those updates will always be visible to other threads.

But I wonder if `putAll` operation is thread safe and atomic? Say, I want to update my cache simply by invoking `putAll` and passing a `Map` with actual values.
Say, I want to get some value from cache while it is being updated. Will I receive an old value or wait till the cache is updated and receive a new value?

Comment: Threadsafe and Atomic are two distinct notions.  Atomic operations are necessarily threadsafe, but thread safety does not require thata given operation is atomic.  As long as the atomic operations that make up a larger operation leave the cache in a consistent state (e.g. no created-but-unpopulated entries), then the larger operation might be considered thread safe.  Based on the following: http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache.html#putAll(java.util.Collection) I would surmise that a putall is not atomic

Answer (score 3):

An operation is atomic when the operation can be only performed entirely or not performed at all. According to [Interface Ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/3.0.2/org/ehcache/Cache.html) the `putAll` operation is not atomic.

> This method will throw a NullPointerException if a null element or null key is encountered in the collection, and a partial completion may result (as only some of the elements may have been put).

Regarding if ehcache is threadsafe or not. Ehcache is especially designed to be threadsafe. Take for example the [Cache](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html#putAll(java.util.Collection)) implementation.

> Cache is threadsafe.

But beware threadsafe does not mean synchronized. So what's the difference?

Threadsafe means a class can be used from multiple threads without any errors or problems.

Synchronized means one or more methods can be used only from one thread at the same time.

What does it mean in case of `putAll` and lets say a `get` call. Both methods are threadsafe but they are not synchronized.

Therefore you can't be sure if Thread A calls `putAll` and Thread B calls `get` afterwards that `putAll` is executed before the `get`.

Comment: "you can't be sure if Thread A calls putAll and Thread B calls get afterwards that putAll is executed before the get" and neither can you be sure of that if the methods are synchronized. Synchronized is nothing more than one way to implement thread safety (and atomicity). The description of putAll does *not* preclude it being atomic. The simplest way to implement atomic operations is to just lock the resource. And if you do that you can guarantee that other threads will always see the specified changes or none at all. With your definition a Concurrent*Set.add() method couldn't be atomic either

Comment: @Voo, I think we have different definitions of an atomic operation. And of course if both methods are synchronized  of a class you can be sure that the if a thread calls a method first an other thread call is blocked till the method call of the first thread is finished.

Comment: If your definition makes it impossible for putAll to be atomic it can't be correct because it's trivial to make it atomic (just lock everything). Yes if a null element is encountered it'll throw an exception, but the only definition of atomic that makes sense is that other threads can either see all modifications or none. But you can certainly document a method to throw and do only some work while still being atomic

Comment: @Voo, it's not my definition it's the implementation of putAll which makes it to an non atomic operation '[...] a partial completion may result [...]'. And it's not the question if it's trivial to make the operation atomic or not it's simply not.

Comment: The partial completition is the final result of that call. It's pretty simple: If the specified behavior is that three elements should be inserted (because the fourth was null so the remaining two million elements are ignored due to the exception) and you can see either zero or all three inserted elements the function is atomic, if you could see two elements but not the third it's not.

Comment: @Voo, like I already wrote we have two different definitions of atomicity. I will add some references to make it clear, what an atomic operation is and what not.